# Magento2.3 w/ php7.2 - Emails not being sent

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

I am running Magento 2.3 on php7.2 everything works perfectly, except emails are not being sent to the customers or myself.

I have checked:

- Sales Order Emails set to YES
- Cron tabs configured properly

Is there a bug in M2.3 with regard to sending emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with php7.2 and my server, which from CentOS 6. You need CentOS 7 to run Magento 2.3.1 with php7.2

I changed my php version to 7.1, and all emails are being sent just fine.